# Select all combinations of the rows from 2 tables

Tags: c#, datatable, cartesian-product

I have two datatables like this:

dt1:

```
   ID1
----------
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
```

dt2:

```
   ID2
----------
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

Now, I want to retrieve all combinations of the items from these two datatables such that the result will contain 50 (10 x 5) rows - something like this:

dtResult:

```
ID1     ID2
------------
1        1
1        2
1        3
1        4
1        5
2        1
2        2
2        3
2        4
2        5
3        1
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

is there any simple way instead of using a loop?

Comment: How are you populating the two datatables? From one single database, or from two separate databases?

Comment: Use cross join, in databases theory it is called Cartesian product.

Comment: @alextansc,i have create dt1 by code and dt2 by select query from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all but i have solved it by Foreach method in LINQ.

Answer (score 5):

You are finding for cartesian product. Use `CROSS JOIN`

```
Select a.ID1, b.ID2 
FROM   dt1 A CROSS JOIN dt2 B
```

Answer (score 4):

Do a full join:

```
Select a.ID1, b.ID2 FROM dt1 A,dt2 B
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "full join". Most people would probably interpret that as a full outer join which is clearly not what we're talking about here. The query you provided is correct, of course.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ:

```
var combinedRows = from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                   from b in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                   select new { ColumnID1 = a["ID1"], ColumnID2 = b["ID2"] };
        foreach (var item in combinedRows)
        {
            row = dt3.NewRow();
            row["ID1"] = item.ColumnID1;
            row["ID2"] = item.ColumnID2;
            dt3.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
            new DataColumn("ID1") });

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                dt1.Rows.Add(i + 1);

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
            new DataColumn("ID2") });

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                dt2.Rows.Add(i + 1);

            var queryOne = from row in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                           from row1 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                           select new
                           {
                               id1 = row.Field<string>("ID1"),
                               id2 = row1.Field<string>("ID2")
                           };

            var result = queryOne.ToList();
```